# Angularjs Transclude element with ng-options

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-transclude

I got a directive with `transclude: element` and i want to apply a template to a select element with ng-options, to wrap the select with the given template.

```
app.directive("ngSelect", function(){
  return {
  restrict: "A",
  replace:true,
  transclude: 'element',
  templateUrl: function(elem,attrs) {
     return 'select.html';
  },
  ...
  compile: function compile(cElement, cAttrs, cTransclude) {
    return{
      pre: function preLink(scope, aElement, aAttrs, aController){

      },
      post: function postLink(scope, aElement, aAttrs, aController){

      }
    }
```

Usage:

```
<select ng-select ng-label="Select 2" ng-model="data.select2" required ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in list"></select>
```

But for some reason what's beeing wrapped are the options from the ng-options and not the select itself, as you can see in the final DOM here.

```
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2  ..."> 
     <option value="?"selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="number:1" label="value1">value 1</option>
     <option value="number:2" label="value 2">value2</option>
     <option value="number:3" label="value 3">value</option>
  </div>
```

I think the select element is removed at some point of the transclusion, but i'm not realy sure. All i found about `ngOptions` with `tranclude: element` was a bit confusing.

How can i get this select to work properly with `tranclude: element` and `ngOptions`? Can i do something in the compile/pre/post link functions?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TL6I2KE9Kd5PQqNC0tIQ?p=preview).

Comment: The question should be self-contained without relying on external links, like plunker. So, pls paste the relevant code in the question. Also, what are you (or is this directive) actually trying to achieve. It's not enough to say "I have a directive with `transclude: "element"` - *why* do you have is just as important. Is this directive trying to wrap the `<select>` in a template?

Comment: @NewDev See edited question